# Swift Generated Header Missing Objective-C Property

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift-extensions

I have a core data generated class called Message. Message has a message property that for some reason is inaccessible in Swift.

You can clearly see the message property here in the header file
[image: You can clearly see the message property here in the header file]

In a Swift extension of Message I'm unable to access the message property
[image: In a Swift extension of Message I'm unable to access the message property]

Upon digging around further I found that the property doesn't even exist in the corresponding generated Swift file for Message+CoreDataProperties.h

[image: Upon digging around further I found that the property doesn't even exist in the corresponding generated Swift file for Message+CoreDataProperties.h]

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the type of message, it is a data type, initialize it

Comment: The type is defined in the objective-c header. You can see in the first screenshot.

`@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *message`